# how to get the values and proceed to the next incrementing id at the same time in mysql using select st

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, pdo

I'm currently facing a problem in mysql. I have this first id that i got from jquery which is like 398(from user1) and so on incrementing till 700 with other users input too. i managed to pass the grabbed value from jquery to the mysql query. But, here is the problem i need to increment the value of the id from 398 to the next id which is 400(the next id is randomly 405) i can't seem to find a good soln on the internet after googling. The soln's are too abstract for me. So, far, couldn't understand how i can select from updates table the correct next incrementing id pertaining to that user1&user2. is, there a way to do it in mysql with the jquery value which isn't incrementing, using php is also good for me.

here is the mysql query:

```
public function totalUpdates($friend,$session,$update_id1,$update_id2, $load) {
    try{
    $sql2="SELECT distinct update_id,update_body,time,title,user_id_u,account_name,author,data FROM updates where author in (:friend,:session) and update_id not in(:update_id1, :update_id2) order by time desc limit $load,2";
        $stmth=  $this->_db->prepare($sql2);//Check here syntax of $db 
    $stmth->bindValue(":session",$session);
    $stmth->bindValue(":friend",$friend);
    $stmth->bindValue(":update_id1",$update_id1);
    $stmth->bindValue(":update_id2",$update_id2);
    $stmth->execute();
    return $stmth->fetchAll();
    } catch (PDOException $ei){
        echo $ei->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the last ID you worked with, and want the next id?

```
SELECT id FROM wherever WHERE id > $lastId ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT1
```

Comment: i got the first id but after the ajax loading the problem is that jquery still points to the old id eg) if i got the first id as 398 through jquery and after using the infinite scrolling page script it still fetches the 398 as the first and not the newly loaded value in DOM. i seem to get the last id correctly through jquery and not the newly loaded first value thats why im asking if i could get to the next incrementing value with the first id got through jquery in mysql. @delboy1978uk

Comment: You *could* try setting the last ID as a session var, then set the new id in the session before the script ends. subsequent requests can check whether to set an ID based on the session var being there or not?